# C++ to C# array declaration

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I want to convert the below code to C#:

```
struct Elf32_Ehdr {
  uint8   e_ident[16];   // Magic number and other info
  uint16  e_type;        // Object file type
  uint16  e_machine;     // Architecture
  uint32  e_version;     // Object file version
  uint32  e_entry;       // Entry point virtual address
  uint32  e_phoff;       // Program header table file offset
  uint32  e_shoff;       // Section header table file offset
  uint32  e_flags;       // Processor-specific flags
  uint16  e_ehsize;      // ELF header size in bytes
  uint16  e_phentsize;   // Program header table entry size
  uint16  e_phnum;       // Program header table entry count
  uint16  e_shentsize;   // Section header table entry size
  uint16  e_shnum;       // Section header table entry count
  uint16  e_shstrndx;    // Section header string table index
};
```

Apparently, it maps to different casing.
uint16   -> UInt16
uint32   -> UInt32
uint64   -> UInt64

And apparently, uint8 maps to Byte.

The problem is:

```
Byte   e_ident[16];   // Magic number and other info<br />
```

won't compile, it says: Array size cannot be declared in variable declaration...

What, no fixed size array without new?

Is that correct to map it to this:

```
Byte[] e_ident = new Byte[16];   // Magic number and other info
```

or will that turn out to be entirely wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need the [Structlayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) and MarshalAs attributes, and use it something like:

```
//untested
[Structlayout]
struct Elf32_Ehdr 
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
  Byte   e_ident[16];   // Magic number and other info
  Uint16  e_type;       // Object file type
  ...
}
```

But consider this a hint for further searching, it's not something I know a lot about.

Comment: It doesn't compile, yet the highest voted answer.  Odd place, isn't it?

Comment: @Hans, it was from memory, that's what the //untested flag is for. I never claimed/pretended it compiled. It seems to work as a pointer though. And you were simply 3 hours late (-:
.

Comment: I know, kinda grumpy this afternoon.  Deleted a bunch of good answers, stuff that compiled.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [fixed-size buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) - although this requires the structure to be declared in unsafe code:

```
unsafe struct Elf32_Ehdr
{
    fixed byte e_ident[16];
    ushort type;
    // etc
}
```

You may *also* need `[StructLayout(StructLayoutKind.Sequential)]` or `[StructLayout(StructLayoutKind.Explicit)]`. Basically the fixed-size buffer makes sure that the data is inline, rather than creating a separate array which needs cunning marshalling.